# How do I read a tab-delimited text file into R on a Mac?

Tags: r, macos, matrix, input

I've got a tab-delimited text file which I generated by pasting a table from an excel sheet into a text file and I'm trying to read the data into **R** on a Mac. I get the following output

```
system.file("path/to/file.txt")
[1]""
no lines available in input
```

If I try loading the text file using the 'Source script or load data in R' button, I get:

```
1:          col1    col2
                    ^
/path/to/file: unexpected symbol
```

I thought this might be the tabs but then I added

```
sep='\t'
```

to my read.table line and that still doesn't work - any suggestions?

The data is in the format of a matrix, with no entry on the first col/first row entry for the row names, which are the first column

Comment: Use `read.table("path/to/file", sep="\t")` instead. It says in the help of `system.file` that it "Finds the full file names of files in packages etc.", which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I find trying to figure out this path stuff is to mess about: `getwd()` and `setwd()`. First, type

```
getwd()
```

in your R terminal. This will give your *working* directory. It also gives you an idea of how to specify the path to your file! The function `setwd` sets the working directory.

Now you have the correct path in the correct format, you just need to use:

```
##For csv files
read.csv(....)
##For tab delimited files
read.delim(....)
##For other files - you can specify `sep` to `\t` if you wish.
read.table(....)
```